# Get 2 concecutive words from a list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of sentences broken into words. I'm trying to find the word 'good morning' and get the prefix and suffix word from that sentence and append it to list.

#### List of sentences

```
list_t = [['welcome','to','this','show','good','morning','how','can','we'],['lets', 'get', 'this','done','together', 'in','a','single','plane'], ['hi','guys','this','good','morning','show','will','be','aired']]
```

#### Word to find in above list

```
find_me = ['good morning']
```

#### Code

```
l_append_prefix ,l_append_suffix =[] ,[]
    for i, w in enumerate(list_t [:10]):
    for j, x in enumerate(w):

        try:
            if x == "good":
                if x[j+1] == "morning":
                    print(x)
        except:
            pass

 #Another Approach
 for ind,sent in enumerate(list_t[:1]):
     #I get the index of the word
     sent.index("right time")
```

#### Expected Output

```
l_append_prefix = ['show','this']
l_append_suffix = ['how','show']
```

Comment: What is the question? Why the expected result of first element of `l_append_prefix` is `'this'`? What is `find_me` used for?

Comment: Made the necessary changes in the output file. 'find_me'  contains concecutive words which need to find in the list and get prefix and suffix of that f'ind_me' word

Comment: Still can't find a question? Still, what is `find_me` used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for 1st element in the list.
It will be something like this:

```
l = list_t[0]

prefix = []
suffix = []
for idx, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(l, l[1:])):
#     print(first, second)
    if (first=="good") and (second =="morning"):
        print(idx-1)
        print(idx+2)
        if (idx-1>0):
            prefix.append(l[idx-1])
        if (idx+2<len(l)):
            suffix.append(l[idx+2])
```

---

**prefix:** `['show']`

**suffix:** `['how']`

You can add loop and modify it to make it work.

**Complete solution:**

```
prefix = []
suffix = []
for l in list_t:
    for idx, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(l, l[1:])):
        if (first=="good") and (second =="morning"):
            if (idx-1>0):
                prefix.append(l[idx-1])
            if (idx+2<len(l)):
                suffix.append(l[idx+2])
```

---

**prefix:**

```
['show', 'this']
```

**suffix:**

```
['how', 'show']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first, second = find_me[0].split()
l_append_prefix, l_append_suffix =[] ,[]

for sentence in list_t:
    for i in range(len(sentence) - 1):
        if sentence[i] == first and sentence[i+1] == second:
            before = i - 1
            after  = i + 2
            if before >= 0:
                l_append_prefix.append(sentence[before])
            if after < len(sentence):
                l_append_suffix.append(sentence[after])
```

The result:

> ```
> l_append_prefix = ['show','this']
> l_append_suffix = ['how','show']
> ```